# Create raster from numpy array with boundaries

Tags: python, raster, gdal, array, boundaries

Working on creating a raster with a constant value for all pixels for land with python. A sample raster is read to get the projection, geotransformation for the the new raster. The raster has the US map. The input raster pixel values are read as an array and converted to array with ones and written into the new raster. Is it possible to restrict to have only the land area have value:1 and the ocean and seas have value:0.

Is it possible to apply a mask to the numpy array so that only the contiguous 48 US states have value:1?

Added code. Getting the lat, long for each pixel and checking if it's part of the contiguous 48 US. Some of the functions are from previous answers here.

Update:
Removed code as it was the wrong approach.

Comment: Yes it is.  But you'll need to be more specific with your problem and show your code attempt if you want more specific answers.

Comment: @mikewatt Added code now. Looks like it may be easier to create a raster of the contiguous US as mask using qgis. I am new to gis.

Comment: You can use `gdal.RasterizeLayer()` to create your mask from a vector source, instead of manually checking each pixel for intersection.  I highly recommend using rasterio over the python bindings for gdal, though, unless you're bound to gdal for some reason.  https://rasterio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/rasterio.features.html#rasterio.features.geometry_mask

Comment: @mikewatt Thanks. Will look into rasterio. Was able to create a raster with gdal_rasterize, which seems to have worked.